# ComputedProperty doesn't get updated

Tags: ember.js

I have this test application which should print "filtered" and "changed" each time the applications view is clicked, because a computed property is called. However the property binding is only triggered when updating the property with an empty array:

```js
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  Settings: Ember.Object.create({
    filter: []
  }),

  ApplicationView: Ember.View.extend({
    click: function(event) {
      filter = App.get('Settings.filter');
      console.dir(filter);
      if (App.get('Room.filtered')) {
        filter = filter.filter(function(item) {
          return item != App.get('Room.name');
        });
      } else {
        filter.push(App.get('Room.name'));
      }
      App.set('Settings.filter', filter);
    }
  })
});

Room = Ember.Object.extend({
 name: "test",
 _filterer: function() {
   console.dir("changed");
 }.observes('filtered'),
 filtered: function() {
   console.dir("filtered");
   filter = App.get('Settings.filter');
   for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
     if (filter[i] == this.get('name')) return true;
   }
   return false;
 }.property('App.Settings.filter', 'name').volatile()
});

App.Room = Room.create();

setTimeout(function() {App.set('Settings.filter', ['test']); }, 3000);
```

Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/edolol/2/edit

Why is the property binding only triggered when setting the Setting to an empty array? And why does it trigger when doing it manually in the timeout?

## Update

Here is a working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/edolol/11/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're going to add/remove items from an array, and not change the entire array, you need to inform the computed property to observe the items inside the array, not only the array itself:

The syntax is:

```
function() {
}.property('App.settings.filter.@each')
```

The reason it was working with `setTimeout` is because you were replacing the entire array instead of the items inside it.

I fixed your jsbin: http://jsbin.com/edolol/10/edit

I fixed some minor other stuff such as `filter.push` is now `filter.pushObject` (Using Ember's [`MutableArray`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html)).

And after changing the filter array (`filter = filter.filter()`) you need to set the new `filter` variable as the property: `App.set('Settings.filter', filter);`

Comment: Is the conversion from [] to MutableArray happening automatically? The `.@each` stuff won't work without your minor modifications (as you can see if you cycle from revision 3 to 9 of the jsbin).

Comment: Yes, Ember converts all arrays automatically to `MutableArray`. you can just define an array var a = [], and use `a.forEach`, `a.pushObject`, `a.find` and all other functions.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that I have used `.push()` to add to `App.Settings.filter` and `.filter()` to remove from it. The first approach does not create a new array, the latter does. Thats why removing from that array has worked, but not adding.

I assume that using `Ember.ArrayProxy` and an observer for `.@each` would have worked. But thats out of my knowledge. This little problem is solved by just creating a new array though.

```js
filter = App.get('Settings.filter').slice(0);
```